# Google Maps Javascript two InfoWindow for the same marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I would like to add an infoWindow that is always visible (like the title label but always visible) and another which is shown  when the user clicks on the marker (aka the normal behavior).
Currently my for loop for adding the markers look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];
        var icon = "";
        icon = "/images/map-icon.png";
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
        });

        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);

                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  Do you want the "dynamic"/onclick InfoWindow to cover the "always there" one?  If not how do you expect them to be arranged?  Are you just looking for a persistent label for the maker?

Comment: Yes I want to that the onclick InfoWindow replace/hide the always there while its active.

Comment: What content do you want in the dynamic InfoWindow? What content goes in the fixed one?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: The content in both InfoWindow is html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:  Create a fixed InfoWindow for each marker, opened when created, then one dynamic InfoWindow with the "normal" InfoWindow behavior which opens on top of the fixed InfoWindow.

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var data = markers[i];
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
  bounds.extend(position);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    title: data.title,
  });
  // fixed always open InfoWindow
  marker.iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  marker.iw.setContent(data.title);
  marker.iw.open(map, marker);

  // dynamic InfoWindow, opened on click
  (function(marker, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
      infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  })(marker, data);

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/80L7jfue/4/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: -33.9,
      lng: 151.2
    }
  });

  setMarkers(map);
}

var markers = [{
    description: 'Bondi Beach',
    lat: -33.89042,
    lng: 151.274856,
    title: "Bondi"
  },
  {
    description: 'Coogee Beach',
    lat: -33.923036,
    lng: 151.259052,
    title: "Coogee"
  },
  {
    description: 'Cronulla Beach',
    lat: -34.028249,
    lng: 151.157507,
    title: "Cronulla"
  },
  {
    description: 'Manly Beach',
    lat: -33.80010128657071,
    lng: 151.28747820854187,
    title: "Manly"
  },
  {
    description: 'Maroubra Beach',
    lat: -33.950198,
    lng: 151.259302,
    title: "Maroubra"
  }
];

function setMarkers(map) {
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i];
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: data.title,
    });
    marker.iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker.iw, 'domready', function() {
      // warning relies on undocumented API behavior
      $("button.gm-ui-hover-effect").hide();
    });
    marker.iw.setContent(data.title);
    marker.iw.open(map, marker);


    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);

        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you your answer worked perfectly. The only change to your code I needed to made is to set the z-index (.setZIndex(Number)) because with html content the z-index is not calculated correctly and the static InfoWindow had bigger value than the one that opened on click.